# Python:Call a function from within another function

Tags: python, function

I have two functions, and I would like to call one function from the other.

```
def first_contains_second(word1, word2):
    if word1 in word2:
        return True
    return False

def one_contains_another(word1, word2):
    if word1 in word2 or word2 in word1:
        return True
    return False
```

Example would be

```
print(first_contains_second("apple", "ppl"))
print(one_contains_another("ppl", "apple"))
```

Comment: `first_contains_second` function does not pull its weight. Use `word1 in word2` directly in your conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
def one_contains_another(word1, word2):
    if first_contains_second(word1, word2) or first_contains_second(word2, word1):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decorators, look at this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/).